# How to show jDialog from clicked in Jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jdialog, mouseclick-event

I try to show `JDialog` when I click `JTable` but my dialog didn't show.

It is my code :

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if (evt.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
       dlgCoba dlg = new dlgCoba();
       dlg.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Does this event ever get triggered?

Comment: sometimes there are other properties that dont let you dialog be shown, for example it must be at front...

Comment: Please take care of 'Naming convention'. Your class name should be started with a capital letter. Can you post the code in 'dlgCoba' class.

Comment: @MatiasCaamaño: I don't understand what you are referring to. What do you mean by "it must be at front". Please clarify. Note, I'm not the original poster, and I feel that I understand Swing and JDialogs pretty well.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i mean that the Jdialog can be hidden by another component...

Comment: @MatiasCaamaño: I've never seen that happen, except perhaps rarely with mixing heavy and light weight components, but we don't see that here. In what situations do you mean?

Comment: I suspect that the cell is editable and is consuming the mouse event before it gets to you.  If it's not required, make sure that the cells in question are not editable

Comment: the cell is not editable and when i click jTable the messagae error is 
"GroupLayout can only be used with one Container at a time"